# how to split a string and stored in a php variable

Tags: php

I will split a long string into 3 parts.how will it  can be stored in 3 different variables in php. the code is

```
<?php
$str = "Q5vRFsC+6Rs08JlvWDMc/sqwR6MpPTzO/p6UH+bPDBE=";
$parts = str_split($str, strlen($str)/3+1);
print_r($parts);
?>
```

The output is

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Q5vRFsC+6Rs08Jl 
    [1] => vWDMc/sqwR6MpPT 
    [2] => zO/p6UH+bPDBE= 
)
```

pls help me

Comment: And whats your problem now?

Comment: the string length is not a  dividend of 3

Comment: `strlen()` is `15` and `15/3 = 5` ?!

Comment: Please specify your question more!

Comment: I want a output like this. $a=Q5vRFsC+6Rs08Jl  $b=vWDMc/sqwR6MpPT  $c=zO/p6UH+bPDBE=

Comment: @user3064621 Are you looking for something like in my answer? If not i don't see what you want?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$str = "Q5vRFsC+6Rs08JlvWDMc/sqwR6MpPTzO/p6UH+bPDBE=";
$parts = str_split($str, strlen($str)/3+1);
echo "a = " . $a = $parts[0] . "<br />";
echo "b = " . $b = $parts[1] . "<br />";
echo "c = " . $c = $parts[2] . "<br />";
```

Output:

```
a = Q5vRFsC+6Rs08Jl
b = vWDMc/sqwR6MpPT
c = zO/p6UH+bPDBE=
```

With this code you can output `$a`, `$b`, `$c` and get the single parts of the string

Comment: ya...this is working

Comment: @user3064621 Your welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: maybe try next time to specify your question more :D)

Answer (score 1):

All you simply need is

```
$str = "Q5vRFsC+6Rs08JlvWDMc/sqwR6MpPTzO/p6UH+bPDBE=";
list($a,$b,$c) = str_split($str, strlen($str)/3+1);
```

The variables `$a`, `$b` and `$c` contain your desired values.

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/226987)**

Comment: I think the problem was more a print/ design problem! Like OP wanted a special output(echo). But your answer is with distance the best!

Answer (score 0):

The code is simple,

```
$string1 = $parts[0];
$string2 = $parts[1];
$string3 = $parts[2];
```

That is so simple, the point to be noted here is that this site is not for a learning programmer, you need to perform some basic research before posting a question here.

Comment: this is not much as simple I think,the code suggested you is also not working for me.

Comment: Can you tell me what do you mean by not working? or tell me what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: your suggested part of code and the code in the main question should gave the same above mentioned result

Comment: The situation is this: Array ( [0] => Q5vRFsC+6Rs08Jl [1] => vWDMc/sqwR6MpPT [2] => zO/p6UH+bPDBE= ) The goal is : $a=Q5vRFsC+6Rs08Jl $b=vWDMc/sqwR6MpPT $c=zO/p6UH+bPDBE=

Comment: I did not get the point abut this comment. Can you elaborate

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$str = "Q5vRFsC+6Rs08JlvWDMc/sqwR6MpPTzO/p6UH+bPDBE=";
$parts = str_split($str, ceil(strlen($str)/3));
print_r($parts);
$part1 = $parts[0];
$part2 = $parts[1];
$part3 = $parts[2];
?>
```

Comment: Good thing you didn't test your own code! BECAUSE it does not work

Comment: Nice now you only have to explain me what's the difference to the output from OP's code?

Comment: the above code shows the same output and their is no change in it

Comment: @user3064621 You have to specify your question like: this is the situation and this is my goal! I don't see your goal!

Comment: is the question is why ceil again?? @Rizier123,@user3064621

Comment: I want a output like this. $a=Q5vRFsC+6Rs08Jl $b=vWDMc/sqwR6MpPT $c=zO/p6UH+bPDBE= –

Comment: Both code,I mean code in the question and the code just above give same result

Comment: The situation is this:   Array ( 
    [0] => Q5vRFsC+6Rs08Jl 
    [1] => vWDMc/sqwR6MpPT 
    [2] => zO/p6UH+bPDBE= 
)    The goal is :  $a=Q5vRFsC+6Rs08Jl $b=vWDMc/sqwR6MpPT $c=zO/p6UH+bPDBE=

Comment: no @user3064621 check this out at http://ideone.com/Sy3wli. you will find the difference.

Comment: @user3510665 WoW you answered a question from user3064621 18h ago and now your saying your own code from the other question is false.

Comment: See mr. @Rizier123 im not a accurate programmer like you. mistakes may happen. and im trying to correct it.

Comment: Even though this isn't the answer the OP is looking for, using `ceil()` does seem like a better solution to me than adding 1.  In a case where string length is something like `30`, ceil will split it into three parts of `10` while adding one would be `11`, `11`, and `8`.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: Sure and thnks @TarynEast